# Deleting photo in Maximo Anywhere

Tags: maximo-anywhere

I am working on Maximo Anywhere 7.6.1. I would like to know is there any way in which we can delete attachment from Maximo anywhere? Since its not possible to call doclinks table from anywhere what are the other way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

The only option we have right now is the "si.attachment.basedirectory" 
Global property in the Anywhere Administration application

The  "si.attachment.basedirectory" Global property controls the location of the base directory for attachments.

If a mobile device is shared, attachments are added to multiple user directories, 
with one directory per user.

All of the user directories are located under the base directory. To free up the space that is taken up by attachments, delete the attachments within the user directories or delete the default directory.